# Ruby on Rails has_many -- creating associations for individual records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, orm, associations

Here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
end
```

The number of dogs is small however, and I want to be able to refer to each one by an individual name. I want to have something like this in the end:

```
@barry = new User(name: 'Barry')
@barry.rover
@barry.patch.weight
```

How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't think it's a good idea, but you could try something like this:

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  dogs.find_by(name: name) or super(name, *args, &block)
end
```

But it will not create an association for you.

The code above is written with assumption `Dog` model has `name` attribute. Now you're able to do:

```
barry = User.create(name: 'Barry')
barry.dogs.create(name: 'rover', weight: 12)
barry.dogs.create(name: 'patch', weight: 8)
barry.rover        #=> #<Node name: 'rover' weight: 12>
barry.patch.weight #=> 8
barry.other        #=> error
```

Comment: `.where(name: name).first` -> `find_by`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand `.where(name: name).first` -> `find_by`. Could you expand or give an example please?

Comment: Thank you, I was being slow, it makes sense!

Comment: Guys just a heads up, with your help I understand this better, and I now realise I should have asked the question differently. So I've posted a different but similar question on SO.